# Is the Compare Validator Bugged

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

This is very basic but it always returns false on the compare validation. Anyone else running in to this problem?

```
 public class UsersRegisterUserViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("E-Mail Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-Mail Address is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+@(([A-Za-z0-9\-])+\.)+([A-Za-z\-])+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid E-mail Address")]
    public string RegUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must match")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string RegConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yep - having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

```
adapters.add("equalto", ["other"], function (options) {
    var prefix = getModelPrefix(options.element.name),
        other = options.params.other,
        fullOtherName = appendModelPrefix(other, prefix),
        //element = $(options.form).find(":input[name=" + fullOtherName + "]")[0];
        element = $(options.form).find(":input[name='" + fullOtherName + "']")[0];
```

Comment: nope! Still broke even in the updated scripts from the tools update

Answer (score 1):

MVC3 Compare attribute is buggy when comparing passwords independently of Account Controller.  It seems it is hardcoded to only work with Account controller.
1. Cut and past email, password, confirm password from RegisterModel into a new file called ViewModels/ShortRegister.cs
2. Cut razor code ( email, password, confirm password) from register view and past it into partial view, call it "_shortRegistration".
3. Create a new controller called "ShortRegistration".  Add the partial view into ShortRegistation.
5. Add related jquery scripts

1. Create a link on home page to ShortRegistration.
2. Confirmation error message always fires error message.
3. Remove the email from the partial view confirmation, The Compare functionality works.
4. Add userName to the partial view and view-model, Compare functionality fails, again password confirmation error message always displays error message.

Has this bug been fixed?  I disabled Compare attribute and wrote jquery and CCS to fix this!  I am more than happy to email the code to prove that Compare is buggy.

Comment: There is a posted fix for this, let me know if you need the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, no, I am not running into such problems. I've just tested the following code and it worked perfectly fine as expected.

Model:

```
public class UsersRegisterUserViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("E-Mail Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-Mail Address is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+@(([A-Za-z0-9\-])+\.)+([A-Za-z\-])+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid E-mail Address")]
    public string RegUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must match")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string RegConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new UsersRegisterUserViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UsersRegisterUserViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model UsersRegisterUserViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RegUsername)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RegUsername)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RegUsername)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RegConfirmPassword)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RegConfirmPassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RegConfirmPassword)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

So now the question becomes: how is your code different than mine?

Comment: Where do you get the latest version of the MS supported Jquery libs?

Comment: @CrazyCoderz, from VS2010 => I simply created a new ASP.NET MVC 3 Project using the default template (I've installed the Tools Update).

Comment: amazing what fixing some quotes will do.. Jeez, I want my 3 hours back :)

Comment: I may have not updated my scripts directory for this project after I installed the tools update. Will create a skeleton project and grab the scripts

Comment: I still ran into the same problem after copying the scripts from a skeleton project. I copied the script with the fixed quotes over and it works. I am using a partial view for my registration, not sure that would make a difference though.