# ASP.NET MVC3 compare validator not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have set compare attribute for comparing passwords as explained in [this](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/01/CompareAttributeASPNETMVC3.aspx) blog.
But it's not working. When I googled about it I found that it's a known bug in jquery.validate.js file.

[Is the Compare Validator Bugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335891/is-the-compare-validator-bugged)

[Asp.net forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/1716181/4577449.aspx/1?Re%20MVC3%20unobtrusive%20validation%20with%20compare%20validator)

I tried the solutions given in above links but no success.

Comment: There's always server side validation... :) ...that *does* work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

You are mixing server and client side. The DataAnnotation Attribute `CompareAttribute` works only on server side.

But you can get similar functionality using the jQuery validation plugin.

#### Sample

```
$.validator.addMethod("yourMethodName", function(value, element) {
    // compare and return
}
```

#### More Information

Check out theese two tutorials.

- [How to use jQuery Validator to compare two fields](http://pinoytech.org/question/8090485/how-to-use-jquery-validator-to-compare-two-fields)
- [compare 2 multi select field using jquery validation](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/compare-2-multi-select-field-using-jquery-validation)